# redis fails after some time

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis

I'm running a redis container with no replication when I let the server run for some time it starts repeating this error

> Timeout connecting to the MASTER... Reconnecting to MASTER
> xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8886 after failure MASTER <-> REPLICA sync started Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event. Master replied to PING,
> replication can continue...

I also tried to set up a replica which produced the same error with an additional line of

> Master is currently unable to PSYNC but should be in the future: -NOMASTERLINK Can't SYNC while not connected with my master

```
  redis:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/redis:7.0
    environment:
      # ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is recommended only for development.
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
      - REDIS_DISABLE_COMMANDS=FLUSHDB,FLUSHALL
      - REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE=master
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - 'redis_data:/bitnami/redis/data'
```

Comment: Can you show result of redis info

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same problem, wondering what it can be.